# How to update openJDK to version 11 in unity editor plugin

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, java-11, openjdk-11

I want to update gradle plugin to 7.0 and above and jdk version to 11 from 1.8.

In prefernces -> external tools I want to update to jdk 11 how can I do that?

Comment: Why? Upgrading these tools probably won't help as Unity expects specific versions to be there, otherwise builds will fail.